# About the execution order of the two lines of code(Powershell)

Tags: powershell

If

```
Get-NetAdapter | Select-Object Name
Read-Host "Please input"
```

It will request input first:

```
Please input: 1
Name                         
----                                                                  
VMware Network Adapter VMnet1
1
```

If

```
Get-NetAdapter | Sort-Object Name
Read-Host "Please input"
```

Output

```
Name                         
----                                                                  
VMware Network Adapter VMnet1
Please input: 1
1
```

Why `Select-Object` requests input first?

Comment: Powershell, powershell core? ISE, VSCode or powershell terminal? What do you use?

Comment: In windows' native powershell

Comment: I believe that the `Get-NetAdapter | Select-Object Name` command is started, and as long as it get data, another thread starts `Read-Host`, but because it prompts, it cannot print the result of the `Get-NetAdapter` command.

Comment: If add one `pause` between them, the order is pause, input, then `Get-NetAdapter | Select-Object Name`

Comment: Please assign to variable, then use **Out-Host** to force immediate output: "$NetAdapterNames = Get-NetAdapter | Select-Object Name
$NetAdapterNames | Out-Host"

Comment: This works well, but I'm wondering why `Select-Object`'s and `Sort-Object`'s are different

Comment: sort usually blocks until it has the whole list, so maybe it's a little slower